# git not adding changed file after codegen finished, called from bash script

Tags: git

Using https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/ to generate Types from a GraphQL schema, and I'm integrating its usage into a pre-commit hook (Husky), like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname $0)/_/husky.sh"

yarn pretty-quick --staged
[ services/foo/gql/schema.graphql -ot services/foo/src/generated/graphql.ts ] || (echo \"running generation in services/foo after updating .graphql file\" && yarn --cwd ./services/foo gen-ts && git add services/foo/src/generated/graphql.ts && git commit -am "committing after gql codegen" && exit 1)
```

The output is as follows:

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml && yarn prettify
  ✔ Parse configuration
  ✔ Generate outputs
$ npx prettier --write src/
src/generated/graphql.ts 515ms
src/generated/models.ts 46ms
src/graphql/schema.ts 5ms
✨  Done in 3.23s.
yarn run v1.22.5
  Finding changed files since git revision 
  Found 2 changed files.
✅  Everything is awesome!
✨  Done in 1.22s.
[some-commit XXXXXXX] committing after gql codegen
 3 files changed, 14 insertions(+), 14 deletions(-)
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

Which re-compiles everything fine, but then when I do `git status`, I receive the following:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   services/foo/src/generated/graphql.ts

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   services/foo/src/generated/graphql.ts
```

So it's added it, committed it, but then it's still showing up as 1) needing to be committed and 2) needing to be added

What am I missing?

I'm trying to automatically run the generation if that file is modified, then add and commit the changes

Comment: Never use a pre-commit hook to *add* files to a commit. (It does work sometimes. It doesn't work sometimes.) Always use the hook only to *verify that what is to be committed is OK*. Use something else—not the hook—to generate the files *before* running `git commit`. In fact, don't run `git commit` at all: run a program that generates the files, `git add`s the files, and then runs `git commit` *for you*.

Comment: Personal preference is to _never commit generated files_ anyway - just regenerate them as build artefacts on the fly.